# Get list of all tables in microsoft azure tablestorage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to get a list of all tables on Microsoft Azure storage. I am able to connect successfully and read rows from the table if i know the name of the table. There is a method to get list of tables with the following definition:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<CloudTable> ListTables(string prefix = null, TableRequestOptions requestOptions = null, OperationContext operationContext = null);
```

Now my question is if i don't pass any parameters would i expect to get a list of all tables. I tried passing "*" for prefix as well which also didn't seem to yield me any results.

Here is my code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
IEnumerable<CloudTable> tableList = tableClient.ListTables("*");//returns empty list
IEnumerable<CloudTable> tableList = tableClient.ListTables();//returns empty list
```

Answer (score 6):

Code to display all the tables in Azure storage account:

```
public static void list_table()
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_AzureStorageConnectionString"));
    CloudTableClient tableClient = new CloudTableClient(storageAccount.TableEndpoint, storageAccount.Credentials);
    var result = tableClient.ListTables();          
    if(result != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        } 
    }
}
```

The output will be:

[image: .....THE OUTPUT FOR THE ABOVE CODE IS.....]

Answer (score 3):

Does this code work for you? You may want to hard-code the connect string temporarily.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
namespace ConsoleClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MyAccountName;AccountKey=MyAccountKey===";
            var TablesName = GetTablesNameForAzureSubscription(connectionString);
            foreach (var r in TablesName)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());
            } 
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        private static List<string> GetTablesNameForAzureSubscription(string connectionString)
        {            
            CloudStorageAccount account =CloudStorageAccount
                                         .Parse(connectionString);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = new CloudTableClient 
                                       (account.TableEndpoint.ToString(),
                                       account.Credentials);
            var result = tableClient.ListTables();
            return result.ToList(); 
        }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine but see my posted answer. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

So turns out my code does indeed work. The client informed me that there were tables but apparently they were mistaken.

NOTE: Using "*" as a prefix does not yield results but not passing any parameters will give list of tables.

Answer (score -1):

**Code:**

```
public static void list_queue()
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_AzureStorageConnectionString"));
            CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

            var result = queueClient.ListQueues();
            if (result != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Please edit your first answer instead of posting it again. (And please don't write all uppercase; this is considered yelling).